# Facebook Apps: Graph API / Integration points with FB Profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Greetings! I am in the process of creating a fairly simple Facebook app but I am getting very mixed and confusing documentation regarding APP integration points with FB Profile.

1) Is it possible to automatically post items from APP to NEWSFEED? (or is this deprecated?)

2) Is it possible to trigger NOTIFICATIONS in the gloabl notifaction drop down for the user? (or is this also deprecated?)

3) OR; are both Notifications + Newsfeed publishing available by using the Graph API now?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. **Yes**, using the [`post`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object
2. **Yes**...and **NO**. Depending on what you mean by notifications, [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) method would appear in the notifications drop down.
3. Welcome to Stackoverflow!